# Error while executing rsync

Tags: rsync

```
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1536) [generator=3.0.9]
```

I get the above error while executing:

```
rsync -a -v -e ssh abc@1.2.3.4:/def/ghi jkl/mno
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometimes with `rsync` if a file, for example, disappears from the source during the course of running `rsync`.

The reason is that `rsync` creates a list of files etc. to transfer, and then goes on to transfer these. There's a race condition in that process whereby a file that was listed might be removed (by the user) before it's transferred.

If the attributes can't be set on the target side, due to permissions, this message will also appear.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the previous errors. Without those, my guess is that you cannot set ownership of the files on the remote side since you're not `root` there.